# Linux switch user and execute command immediately

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I have a scenario where I have to switch to the different user and after that, I need to execute the some Linux command.

my command is something like this

```
( echo myPassword | sudo -S su hduser ) && bash /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

but with this command, I switch to the user and the next command got triggered on the previous user.

Is there any I can accomplish this using shell script

Comment: Be aware that this command saves your password in cleartext in your bash history file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try.

```
sudo -H -u TARGET_USER bash -c 'bash /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh'
```

see [man sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html):

> -H
>
> The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME 
>   environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by 
>   default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the 
>   policy, this may be the default behavior.
>
> -u user
>
> The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a 
>   user other than root. To specify a uid instead of a user name, use #uid. 
>   When running commands as a uid, many shells require that the '#' be 
>   escaped with a backslash ('\'). Security policies may restrict uids to 
>   those listed in the password database. The sudoers policy allows uids 
>   that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw option is 
>   not set. Other security policies may not support this.

Comment: Why `... bash -c 'bash file.sh'`? Couldn't you write it as `... bash file.sh`?

Answer (score 6):

With `su user -c "sh /path/command.sh"` you can run a command as *user*.

I tested with this command:

```
 echo myPassword | sudo -S su - foobar -c "/usr/bin/watch -n 1 cat /etc/resolv.conf"
```

After that the `watch -n` was running as foobar.

So I think your command should work like that:

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S su - hduser -c "bash /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here a shorter version of [αғsнιη's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394469/117549):

```
sudo -Hu user command
# example: sudo -Hu root fish
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

> pkexec - Execute a command as another user
>
> pkexec [--user username] PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]

Comment: tested on my site. But if no home dir exists, then there is an error `Error changing to home directory /home/foobar: No such file or directory`. I created it, but perhaps there is a better solution without home folder